# NoMethodError: undefined method `path' for #<Bundler::Source::Rubygems:0x7f7af5a6d818>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, bundle, bundler

Hi I am trying to setup rails application in my local machine, the rails application developed using rails `3.0.1` and ruby `1.8.7` when am trying to run bundle install command `./bundle exec bundle install` am getting the following error

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `path' for #<Bundler::Source::Rubygems:0x7f7af5a6d818>
```

can any one help me to sort out this issue please.

Answer (score 2):

Try updating your gems by `gem update 'gem outdated | cut -d ' ' -f 1'`.

Comment: Try updating rubygems version

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
gem install rubygems-update
update_rubygems
```